# Save images of different sizes as a pdf

Tags: pdf, image-conversion

I have multiple images, all of different sizes. What I want to do is save each image on its own page in a PDF document, with no white space around it. Would this be possible?

Comment: In windows you can select to print the image, but instead of sending it to the printer you can choose save it as pdf. And no white background

Comment: @D.A I know that, but with different sizes some pages have huge images, while others have chopped-up images. I want it so that each image is on its separate page with no white space.

Comment: maybe [this one](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/download/audio-video-photo/jpgaspdf-10-3329173/) will do the job then

Comment: @D.A It did the job really neatly! Thank you so much! Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I have updated my answer with another, more flexible software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### JPGasPDF

[JPGasPDF](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/download/audio-video-photo/jpgaspdf-10-3329173/) is a portable tool, and requires no installation; simply download the program via the link provided at the bottom, extract the contents of the zip file, and launch the EXE file.

Unfortunately it supports only JPEG and JPG. If I come across any other software as good as that for other type of images , I will update my answer.

### UPDATE:

#### PDF ARCHITECT

I came across [PDF Architect](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfarchitect) a while ago but never used it (I prefer using [FoxIt Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) but it doesn't allow multiple file creation).  So since your question I played around with it a bit and found that you can use it to create a PDF from any file you want. I used png, jpeg, tif. Everything works fine.

It is free to download and gives you a free module ( the Create PDF module - the one we need) when you register the product. It takes some time (10-20 min) to send you the key but do not worry, you can ask them to resend it if it's taking hours.

**How it works:**

Once you are all set up,

1. click the *Create PDF* on the home screen
2. *Combine Files*
3. *Add files* or *Add folder* (Yes you can add entire folders)
4. On the popup screen select your files
5. There are two check buttons at the bottom for additional options
6. Press *Combine*

You are done. A PDF with images of different sizes, no white background and multiple extension files.

**Comment**:

I really hope that FoxIt will add the Combine feature that PDF Architect has, in the future. You will see that it is a much better PDF reader and creator.

Comment: Ok. I will try this. I wish that foxit will provide this functionality in the future since I have it on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do with [Sejda PDF](https://www.sejda.com)'s online [multiple JPG to PDF converter](https://www.sejda.com/jpg-to-pdf).

1. Go to https://www.sejda.com/jpg-to-pdf
2. Drag and drop image files to the page (or open from GDrive/Dropbox)
3. Select **Page size** as *Fit to image*
4. Click **Convert to PDF**, then click **Download** once processing completes.

[image: How to convert JPG to PDF using Sejda's online converter]

Most image formats are supported: png, gif, jpg, tif and bmp.

Free to use within daily limits (3 tasks per day, 30 images per task, 5Mb per image file).

Sejda is an [open source project](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda), I'm one of the devs.

Comment: Thanks, but I have horrible bandwidth(8kB/s upload) so doesn't seem like a great option to me. Seems like a neat solution, though.

Comment: Oh, that bandwidth makes it hard to use online services then. There's also Sejda PDF Desktop: https://www.sejda.com/desktop and you process the files locally on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The "with no whitespace" part is going to be the problem.

While it is easy to print to PDF (Windows 10 has a PDF printer installed by default, or available without needing to install any 3rd party software, and there are plenty of good 3rd party Print-to-PDF tools out there too), you are usually dependent on the image viewer to set up the print, and most consumer image viewers default to fitting the image to a page assuming there needs to be a blank border because normal printers don't print edge-to-edge.

So, you'll need an image viewer or editor that has the ability to print borderless, and preferably on completely custom paper sizes.

The free (but complicated) viewer [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) can do borderless printing, but it appears limited to standard paper sizes.

Next, you'll need a program to merge the individual pages. Frankly, this is the easier part.

[PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/) (PDFsam) is a free application that allows the easy merging of multiple PDFs into a single file. Just now I was able to merge three image-pages (all normal letter size, but two pages were landscape and one portrait) in PDFsam to test this, and it worked.

**Or....**

Just use the one D.A. linked in his comment above. It appears to simplify this process quite a bit. Well done.

Comment: Thanks...  There is no need for multiple tools in general, unless you are looking for that professional look, which is going to cost you. You just need to find the one that does the job. In my updated answer you can see that PDF Architect can do all that, supporting multiple file types. I am sure that there are others that do the same, or even better work

Answer (score 0):

An [online pdf and image merging tool](https://supertool.org/merge-pdf-combine-multiple-pdfs/) is available at https://supertool.org/merge-pdf-combine-multiple-pdfs/

1. Upload files
2. Arrange in the order desired
3. Download

Each PDF page will be the size of the image with no whitespace.